# Turn off alerts on a task list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, alert

We have a SharePoint 2010 solution that uses a standard task list.

We would like to turn off alerts for when items change in / are added to the task list.

Is there a way to do this in code, either when we create the site, or when we add items to the task list?

**Edit**

The solution given by Rob for changing the setting via the UI works fine.

However, we have had problems doing it via code.

Changing the EnableAssignToEmail through code does not affect the value of "Send e-mail when ownership is assigned?".

What is interesting is that setting the "Send e-mail when ownership is assigned?" in the UI from yes to no, will set EnableAssignToEmail to false. But setting it back to yes will not have any affect on EnableAssignToEmail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the task list, go to **List Settings --> Advanced settings**.  There is an "Email Notification" setting that defaults to yes.  Changing it to no should work for you.

To do it programatically from your event receiver: **SPList.EnableAssignToEmail = false;**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enableassigntoemail.aspx